# 5v hall current sensor with a 3v3 mcu

Tags: hall-effect

current sensor (5v) with a 3.3v MCU

I am trying to make a hall effect current sensor (ACS712ELCTR-20A-T) work with a 3.3v MCU.
The current sensor is powered with 5v. I specifically choose this sensor because I need to measure current up to 7A powering a led strip. I know INA219 is easier to use (i2c) but it can only read up to 3A.
My ACS712 has a sensitivy of 100mV/A according to the datasheet.
Here is my code :

```
void getCurrent() {
  //float acs_rest_voltage = (float) (analogRead(currentPin) * (3.3 / 1023));
  float acs_value = 0.0, acs_sum = 0.0, acs_rest_voltage = 2.5;

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    acs_sum += analogRead(currentPin);
    delay(3); // wait for the ADC to settle
  }
  acs_value = acs_sum / 11;

  float currentRaw = ((((acs_value) * (3.3 / 1023.0)) - acs_rest_voltage) / 0.100);

  //current = 2.178956044 * currentRaw - 0.2223241758; // linear regression calibration
  current = currentRaw;

  if (current < 0.0 || current > 321.0) {
    current = 0.0;
  }
}
```

it reads 11 samples, averages them, applies a formula, and returns the current.
The returned current value is so inaccurate that I even tried to apply a linear regression calibration formula.

The wiring is quite simple :
ACS712 has VCC to 5v rail.
MCU (seeeduino xiao) has vcc to 3.3v through a LDO voltage regulator (AMS1117).
So ACS712 and MCU share the same ground.
ACS712 data out pin goes to MCU analog pin (I believe adc is 10 bits) through a voltage divider. I assumed DOUT could output up to 5v so i divided accordingly so the MCU can get 3.3v max data.
This did not work great (inaccurate values).
I was so desperate that I even tried plugging the ACS712 data OUT to the MCU directly. Since my current wont reach more than 10A, i'm confident it wont output more than 3.3v (it outputs 100mv/A)

Here are 2 schematics of 2 options I tried :

[image]

[image]

The voltage measured at ACS712 data out when current is zero is 2.5v

When i increase the current (higher brightness on led strip), here is something weird : the voltage I read with my DMM decreases when the amps increases... ? ? ?

I must be doing something wrong, either circuit or code (or both)

Comment: swap the contacts on the ACS712. it is intended to measure AC with the output oscillating around 2.5 V

Comment: @Juraj I'm afraid I already tried it as well. Believe it or not, it behaves the same : voltage read at the DMM decreases as the current increases

Comment: you can "overclock" an INA219 by adding two more 0.1ohm resistors in parallel with the module's built-in one, then multiplying any read current values by 3.

Comment: @dandavis I will give it a try. How accurate would it be ?I think the problem is the ACS712 chip, I measure voltage at OUT pin with a DMM for currents at 0A, 1A, 2A, 3A : the response is non-linear.

Comment: The output of 2.5V for 0A is as specified by the [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/ACS712.pdf). For increasingly negative currents the voltage will decrease. For increasingly positive currents it will increase. So these symptoms by themselves don't really indicate a problem. Through I would expect the direction of voltage change to switch between positive and negative depending on the direction of the current through the sensing inputs. Are you sure, that this doesn't change, when you swap the input current contacts?

Comment: the ina would be very accurate, and can be calibrated to near perfection. the precision would be 1/3rd of the pre-modification value, which is still pretty good for many things.

Comment: @chrisl You are right. It increases when I switch the inputs. I am confused now because I tried it many times already. Anyways, I really think the acs712 chips are potatoe. The 100mV/A claim is wrong. Quiescent voltage reads 2.5V, when I increase to 1A it wont read 2.6V at my DMM, neither would it read 2.7V when my PSU outputs 2A. Worst : the change is not even something I could translate into something like y=ax+b. The problem with the INA219 is that it is a shunt, not a hall effect, so I can not power the INA with the same power source it reads.